# Rails with jQuery Ajax GET

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This code only outputs the `data` to the console.  No requests are made in the server log.  I'm totally baffled.  My other click handlers are working fine.  Why doesn't my ajax code show anything in the server log, but only the console?  Thank you.

```
# routes.rb
  get 'organize/process' => 'organize#process_selections',
                                 format: :json, as: :organize_process
# organize_controller.rb
  def process_selections
    @selected_huddles = Huddle.includes(:huddle_membership_roles, :users)
                                .find(params[:huddle_ids])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render 'selections', format: :js}
    end
  end

# js (inline with haml)
    $('h2.action').on('click', function() {

      //event.preventDefault();
      var huddle_ids = [];
      $('.card.selected').each(function() {
        huddle_ids.push( $(this).data('huddle-id') );
      });

      $.ajax('#{organize_process_path}', {
        //method: 'GET', (API says default is async/GET)
        //async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({'huddle_ids' : huddle_ids}),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
      });
    });
```

Update: The `data` string is output to the console even when I completely remove the `$.ajax` call.  So the `.each` method is returning too early I think.

Update2: Note that I'm not submitting a form. I don't know if that makes a difference. Thanks again.

Update3: I was using the wrong view. I've got the ajax to send the request, but my formatting is wrong:

```
Started GET "/organize?{%22huddle_ids%22:[1]}" for ::1 at 2016-07-14 01:49:08 -0500
Processing by OrganizeController#select as JSON
  Parameters: {"{\"huddle_ids\":"=>{"1"=>{"}"=>nil}}, "organize"=>{}}
```

Here's my current code for the js and controller:

```
# JS
  $('h2').on('click', '.action', function() {
    //console.log("data", selectedHuddleIds());
    $.ajax('#{organize_process_path}', {
      data: selectedHuddleIds(),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  });

  function selectedHuddleIds() {
    var ids = [], selected_cards = $('.card.selected');
    selected_cards.each(function() {
      ids.push( $(this).data('huddle-id') );
    })
    return JSON.stringify({ 'huddle_ids' : ids });
  }

# controller
  def process_selections
    @selected_huddles = Huddle.includes(:huddle_membership_roles, :users)
                                .find(params[:huddle_ids])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render js: 'selected' }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting the Rails route to be properly expanded by JavaScript. This won't work.

Replace

```
$.ajax('#{organize_process_path}', {
```

with

```
$.ajax('organize/process', {
```

Also, as I referred to in my comment, replace the .each() call with a for loop something like this:

```
$('h2.action').on('click', function() {

  //event.preventDefault();
  var huddle_ids = [];
  var selecteds = $('.card.selected')
  for(var i = 0 i < selelcteds.length; i++) {
    huddle_ids.push( selecteds[i].data('huddle-id') );
  });

  $.ajax('#{organize_process_path}', {
    //method: 'GET', (API says default is async/GET)
    //async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({'huddle_ids' : huddle_ids}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json'
  });
});
```

Comment: Ick. This is why I don't use Haml ;) Perhaps this link helps? http://chrisjmears.com/2009/10/haml-javascript/ Either way, I think you're going to have to get that Rails route expanded properly. <%= "#{organize_process_path}" %> or something.

Comment: Yes, I'm using that syntax.

Comment: Please see my update at the bottom of the post. I think the jquery `each` method is returning too early. Thank you.

Comment: Ah. I see that now. The .each call is asynchronous. It takes a callback function. If you want to force it to be synchronous, which in this case is not unreasonable, replace the .each call with a plain old fashioned for loop. That way the loop will complete before you hit the $.ajax cal.

Comment: Does it matter that I'm not using a form? Just sending json from the ajax call?

Comment: It's hard to say. You don't need a form to make an Ajax call. If you could step through it in the debugger that would help maybe. At a minimum, put a console.log('huddle_ids',  huddle_ids); after the for loop. Also, look at the URL as it is rendered in the browser in the ajax call to make sure it looks right.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to expand the path programmatically, so your answer is most correct, but the problem turned out to be that I was working on the wrong file, with inline `:javascript` haml filter, so my new changes were'nt coming up. Excelsior!

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: '#{organize_process_path}',
  data: JSON.stringify({'huddle_ids' : huddle_ids}),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: This gives the same result, only logging `{"huddle_ids":[1,2]}` in the console.

Comment: Did you check your network tab in your browser and didn't see any xhr reqests? And which console you're referring here? Cause I don't see any `console.log` in your javascript, so I don't think its javascript console.

Comment: I'm using Chrome devtools. The data does go to the console, via the ajax call, but no XHR events happen in that tab.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to attach a screenshot to your question?

Comment: Please see my update at the bottom of the post. I think the jquery `each` method is returning too early. Thank you.